# Conditional Inserting using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to insert a row just below another row base on some condition. Now this code will loop through many sheets. It work fine for 1 sheet, but when it tries to perform the same function for next sheet, it showing error. Can anybody help me to solve the problem. The code I was using is given below:

```
Sub test()
Dim a As Worksheet
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim s As String
Dim z As Variant
s = "Sheet1,Sheet2"
z = VBA.Split(s, ",")
For Each i In z
Set a = Sheets(i)
For lngRow = a.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If UCase$(a.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value) = "R" Then
a.Range("A" & CStr(lngRow + 1)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End If
Next lngRow
Next i
End Sub
```

The error is coming in this row:

```
a.Range("A" & CStr(lngRow + 1)).Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get an error is that you can only `Select` a range on the Active sheet.  To fix your code as is, add `a.Activate` before the `For` loop.

Better still, don't `Select` at all.

Answer (score 1):

your code assumes that Sheets(1) equals sheets("Sheet1") which might not be always the case. better use a code like the following:

```
Sub Test1()
Dim aSht As Variant, SafeShts As String
Dim lngrow As Long

SafeShts = LCase("Sheet3 , Sheet4")   'Write here sheets to be unaffected

For Each aSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If InStr(SafeShts, LCase(aSht.Name)) < 1 Then   'Current sheet not within safe sheets
        For lngrow = aSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If UCase(aSht.Cells(lngrow, 2)) = "R" Then
                aSht.Cells(lngrow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The code doesn't select anything before changes, so it is  pretty fast to.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Apostilos55! I already modified the code based in Chris answer. But your effort is really appreciated.

Comment: User697363, don't be in a hurry. The code above doesn't select/activate anything (as Chris proposed) so it is much faster. Plus the assumption I mentioned at top. Just write the sheet names you want to avoid in the SafeShts string and run it.

Comment: Thanks Apostolos55! I wish I could mark both answer correct. But since that's not possible, and I already marked Chris answer correct, I'm sticking with it. But I'm really grateful for your help.